# Track when a user navigates off of website and update state in dynamoDB

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, session, websocket, session-timeout

Im looking for some way to track when a user connects a disconnects from our angular site. Im looking to Update and store that information in dynamoDB. The main issue Im facing is updating dynamoDB for unexpected closing of the site. So when someone forecloses the bowers, losses internet connection, or even just shuts down their pc.

The only solution I can think of is some heart beat api, that after x amount of time without a beat deans that the user has disconnected. Or use a web-socket to track the connect and disconnect.

Im just looking for other ideas and what you think would be the simplest approach to this.

Comment: That's a tricky problem to solve. My first thought was the web-socket like you mentioned.

Comment: @MarkB is It safe to say I can do this without needed for it to be managed on a server by using the API gateway web-socket? Based on https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/announcing-websocket-apis-in-amazon-api-gateway/ It looks like it can invoke a lambda on connect/disconnect and sending data via routes. Any experience with using this?

Comment: Sorry I don't have experience with API Gateway and websockets, but having it trigger a Lambda on websocket disconnect seems like a great solution to this problem.